# How to enable connection resource pooling with ATL/MSOLEDBSQL?

Tags: c++, oledb, atl

I have ATL code to open sql connection with connection resource pooling enabled.

```
    CDBPropSet  dbinit;
    dbinit[0].SetGUID(DBPROPSET_DBINIT);
    dbinit[0].AddProperty(DBPROP_INIT_OLEDBSERVICES, (long)DBPROPVAL_OS_ENABLEALL);
    CDataSource::OpenWithServiceComponents ("SQLNCLI11", dbinit, 1);
```

**EDIT**
I'm in the process of migrating from SQLNCLI to MSOLEDBSQL, inorder to enable MULTISUBNETFAILOVER option. But I get error when `CDataSource::OpenWithServiceComponents` is invoked with MSOLEDBSQL as the provider with MULTISUBNETFAILOVER.

```
    CDBPropSet  dbinit[2];
    dbinit[0].SetGUID(DBPROPSET_DBINIT);
    dbinit[0].AddProperty(DBPROP_INIT_OLEDBSERVICES, (long)DBPROPVAL_OS_ENABLEALL);
    dbinit[1].SetGUID(DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT);
    dbinit[1].AddProperty(SSPROP_INIT_MULTISUBNETFAILOVER, VARIANT_TRUE));
    CDataSource db;
    db.OpenWithServiceComponents ("MSOLEDBSQL", dbinit, 2);

    HR=0x80040e21, EXCEPTION_UNKNOWN (0x80040E21), No error info available.
```

How do I enable connection resource pooling with ATL/MSOLEDBSQL along with MULTISUBNETFAILOVER enabled?

Comment: Do you have a recent version of the OLE DB Driver for SQL Server?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 you need 18.0.2 or higher

Comment: yes I'm using the latest driver from the above mentioned link. I'm getting this error when I debug inside ATLDBCLI code - `DB_S_ERRORSOCCURRED Multiple-step operation completed with one or more errors. Check each status value`. I see the _dwstatus_ value is 0.

Comment: also to add, `CDataSource::Open` returns success. Only  `CDataSource::OpenWithServiceComponents` returns failure.

Comment: SSPROP_INIT_MULTISUBNETFAILOVER is in the DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT, not in DBPROPSET_DBINIT

Comment: Yes. I had it initialized with DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT. I had missed in the sample that I provided. Now edited it to contain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `AddProperty` utility method that comes with the `CDBPropSet` tool class. You use VARIANT_TRUE which is the correct value for OLEDB but it forces the C++ compiler to use this overload because `VARIANT_TRUE` is a short:

```
bool AddProperty(DWORD dwPropertyID, short nValue, DBPROPOPTIONS propoptions);
```

So, just use a true C++ bool, like this:

```
dbinit[1].AddProperty(SSPROP_INIT_MULTISUBNETFAILOVER, true));
```

And the utility class will pass a VARIANT_TRUE...